# How would I inverse the binary digits (0 and 1) of a matrix in R?

Tags: r

I have created a matrix of binary digits from reading in a pgm file using the R package pixmap but I am trying to inverse the binary digits (making all 0s become 1s and all 1s become 0s) and outputting the matrix again. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
matrix <- +(!matrix)
```

The `!` coerces it into a logical matrix and switches the 0s and 1s to TRUE and FALSE. The `+` coerces it back to 0s and 1s.

Comment: One note is that ```matrix``` is also a function. That's why a lot of other answers used the variable name ```mat``` and you should consider it, too

Answer (score 1):

If you have matrix with 1 and 0's and want to change 1's with 0's and vice versa you can do

```
+(mat == 0)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    1    1    0
#[2,]    1    0    1    1
#[3,]    1    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    1
```

**data**

where original `mat` was :

```
set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(sample(0:1, 16, replace = TRUE), 4)
mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0    0    0    1
#[2,]    0    1    0    0
#[3,]    0    1    1    1
#[4,]    1    1    1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
indOnes <- matrix == 1
indZeros <- matrix == 0
matrix[indOnes] <- 0
matrix[indZeros] <- 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `abs(1-your_matrix)`

```
mat <- matrix(as.numeric(runif(6) > 0.5), 3, 2)

mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    1
#[2,]    1    0    1

abs(1-mat)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    1    0
#[2,]    0    1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can negate the `mat` to return a logical matrix and use `+` to coerce it to binary

```
+!(mat)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    1    1    0
#[2,]    1    0    1    1
#[3,]    1    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    1
```

#### data

set.seed(123)
   mat <- matrix(sample(0:1, 16, replace = TRUE), 4)